# how to group the radio button in html with javascript

Tags: html

One div should select only one radio button and if one div selects test radio than other div should select taining radio.

```
<div><label>Test1<input type="radio" value="test" name="test" /></label>
<label>Training<input type="radio" value="training" name="training" /></label>
</div><hr />
<div>
<label>Test<input type="radio" value="test" name="test" /></label>
<label>Training<input type="radio" value="training" name="training" /></label>
    </div>
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fruitjs/bqn0p79y/)

Comment: The `name` attribute is the radio group, it shouldn't be used with the value's text.

Comment: only one test and one training to be selected, if i select test inn the first div than second div must select training and vice versa.

Comment: You're going to need JS for that.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```js
    var rad = document.myForm1.myRadios;
    var rad2 = document.myForm2.myRadios;

    for(var i = 0; i < rad.length; i++) {
        rad[i].onclick = function() {
            if(this.value==1){
              document.getElementById('f2v2').checked = true;
            } else {
              document.getElementById('f2v1').checked = true;
            }
        }
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < rad2.length; i++) {
        rad2[i].onclick = function() {
            if(this.value==1){
              document.getElementById('f1v2').checked = true;
            } else {
              document.getElementById('f1v1').checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
<form name="myForm1">
    Testing<input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="1" id="f1v1"/>
    Training<input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="2" id="f1v2"/>
</form>

<form name="myForm2">
    Testing<input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="1" id="f2v1"/>
    Training<input type="radio" name="myRadios"  value="2" id="f2v2"/>
</form>
```